# PNG will not load from img tag in html, will load directly on a blackberry 8520 (4.6.1)

Tags: html, blackberry, png, image

I have the damndest problem.  A fairly simple webpage with an embedded png won't load on one particular device I've tested with.  It's a Blackberry Curve 8520 running 4.6.1.  The browser settings are all using the standard Blackbery Browser, e.g. not pointing to Firefox or IE identity.

I've tested it with a really simple cut down html page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="bblogo.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I know the above is technically html5, but that's not the problem it's just short hand included as an example.

The webpage is displayed with a red x for missing image.  Yet the image will view fine if accessed directly, e.g. placing cursor over missing image and selecting Full Image from the blackberry menu.

This is the only device it happens on, other blackberries, iphones and 'droids have been fine.  If I replace the image with a jpg it's fine.  Other png formats are also broken (128 color 8bit png, 24bit no transparency, 24bit with transparency).

So what's going on here and is there a solution?  Is it configuration on the local device or something the BES could be doing to the image when it's embedded in a page but not when it's served directly?

I'm trying to avoid jpgs due to color dithering issues on older mobile phones.

Any advice gratefully received, I'm a complete blackberry newbie so know very very little about the devices or their configuration.  However from what I've read png support should be pretty solid.

Comment: Are you using the default browser? . have you unticked load images in settings?

Comment: What's the size of the image? Is it really big?

Comment: @rihan yes default browser, cannot find a load images option in settings. (**edit** yes, 'Show Images' is ticked in browser configuration.  Browser is Blackberry Browser)  Thanks for the questions... keep em coming.

Comment: @matijs No it's tiny, 150x51 pixels, 8bit 128 color png. around 2kb.

Comment: I'm using gifs now just so I can progress with the work... but I feel dirty. :D

Comment: Have you tried saving the image as a 24-bit PNG? Sometimes these are smaller than their 8-bit cousins. Also, was the previous 8-bit one compressed with anything like ImageOptim?

Comment: Yes, I've tried 24bit pngs both with and without transparency.  The pngs are coming from photoshop cs5 'save for web'.